# Unable to remove index.php under VM environment

Tags: htaccess

I'm having issues removing index.php from the URLs even though mod_rewrite is enabled. My htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    # If 404s, "No Input File" or every URL returns the same thing
    # Use instead of above: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What happens exactly? Do you get a server error? If you still get the index.php in the URL you have to remove it in your config. You have to make sure the value for 'Name of your site's index page' in the config panel is empty.

Comment: Wouter, thanks for the reply, but I got this all fixed here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/unable-to-remove-index-php-under-vm-environment#answer-1954

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer [from another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938330/unable-to-remove-index-php-on-expressionengine-wamp-installation#answer-11906830)

Had to add AllowOverride in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<Directory "C:\Site\Root\Path">
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow  
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```